# Issue with SocketIO, Python-SocketIO and Flask-SocketIO mistmatch

Tags: python-3.x, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio, python-socketio

New to flask and sockets and learning from tutorials. I am having issues getting my client and server to talk to each other through the sockets. Receiving constant 400 errors.
I am running into what seems to be a common issue with version mismatches and have read various posts. However, it seems to me that I have the correct dependencies and the versions.
Error being received:

```
"The client is using an unsupported version of the Socket.IO or Engine.IO protocols"
```

Lots of googling and reading issues with responses from library author shows this is a common dependency issue. However, all my versions seem to be correct for what I am running in my virtual env:

- Flask-SocketIO 5.0.1
- Python-EngineIO 4.0.0
- Python-SocketIO 5.0.4
- npm socket.io 3.10
  I really want to continue with my application but I really am having the hardest time figuring out why my client and server wont communicate via sockets when it appears everything is correct.
  Any assistance is appreciated. Running Debian Linux fyi.

Comment: Share your Flask application log, showing the URLs that the client is requesting, please.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the compatible versions of everything. I'm not sure what javascript version you're using but the versions of the different modules are important.

[image]
source: https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html

The combination I have that is working is as follows:

- socket.io.js 2.2.0
- python-engineio 3.13.2
- python-socketio 4.6.0

You can try a [sample chat app](https://github.com/sonnyparlin/ChatApp) that I have working from my github page.